# data in drop down can't sent to server in IONIC v1

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework

i have some problem when i click some data in drop down in interface data selected but in controller data is null, i don't have idea why in controller data is null
there is my html

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" <i class="icon ion-iphone"></i> >
  <ion-content style="background-color:#818181; background-size: cover;">
    <ion-item  class="row item-text-wrap " >
        <div class="col" style="height: 300px;padding: 0px" id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-item><br>
    <form name="form">
    <div class="button-bar">
<!--    <select style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white">
      <option>864369038803833</option>
      <option>864369038783555</option>
      <option>864369038796698</option>
      <option>864369038797142</option>
      <option>864369038816645</option>
      <option>864369038796946</option>
    </select>-->
        <div>

            <select ng-options="size as size.code for size in sizes " ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>
            <input type="text" value="{{item.code}}"  ng-model="item.code" required/><br>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="rlockbtn()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" >Lock</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="unlock()" >Unlock</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="engine()" >Engine Off</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="button-bar">

        <button class="icon ion-ios-location btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="find()" > Find</button>
        <button class="icon ion-map btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="tracking()" > Tracking</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my controller.js

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, kaka,  $ionicPopup){
  $scope.item ={};
              $scope.code = {};
              $scope.sizes = [ {code: 123456789, name: 'Modul 1'}, {code: 864369038796946, name: 'Modul 4'},
                                {code: 864369038803833, name: 'Modul 5'}, {code: 864369038816645, name: 'Modul 6'},
                                {code: 864369038797142, name: 'Modul 7'}, {code: 864369038796698, name: 'Modul 8'}];
                $scope.update = function() {
                  console.log($scope.item.code, $scope.item.name);
                };
            $scope.rlockbtn = function () {
                kaka.rlock($scope.item.code).success(function (data) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: $scope.item.code,
                            template: 'Lock'
                        });                    
                }).error(function (data) {

                });
            };
})
```

I used http get for send data to server, please help me

Comment: do you see the data being showed in $scope.item.code inside the update function?

Comment: the data not show in update function when i remove update function data still show in interface

Comment: I dont get what you are saying

Comment: in update function data not showed in $scope.item.code

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: sorry i don't create plunker

Comment: rizkaseptiandoyo@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the selected value to the function

```
 <select ng-options="size as size.code for size in sizes " ng-model="item" ng-change="update(item)"></select>
```

in controller:

```
 $scope.update = function(selected) {
   console.log(selected.code, selected.name);
 };
```